# Extracting a string from a dataframe column based on variable length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm very new to python and trying to run a very simple task in which I find a specific character in a dataframe column filled with strings, and then remove all characters to the right. The way I've thought about it is creating a new column with the place of that string appearing, then filtering the first column from 0 to the length of the first time column appearing

```
df['CharIndex'] = df['String Column'].str.find("(",0)
df['Updated Column']=df['StringColumn'].str[0:df['CharIndex']]
```

The indexing column is made fine, then the reformatting column fully NaNs out. Any tips would be appreciated

Edit to show what I'm trying to do, and if there's a better way: So idea would be to take a string column, find the index of the special character, and then create an updated column

```
+-------------------+------------+-----------------+
|     String Column |  CharIndex |  Updated Column |
+-------------------+------------+-----------------+
|     Hello( World  |    5       |    Hello        |
+-------------------+------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: It might make more sense to use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) to grab all of the characters before or after the special character you want? Can you provide sample data and your expected output?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including sample input/output.

Comment: try `str.extract('(\w+)')` should get everything in the parenthisis which is what i assume you are after?

Comment: see updated of what I'm trying to do. @Datanovice unfortunately there isn't a close paren, so I just want to remove everything right of the open paren

Answer (score 0):

Try using split and assinging the value to a new column

```
df['update_column'] = df['String Column'].str.split('\(',expand=True)[0]

print(df)

  String Column  CharIndex Updated Column update_column
0  Hello( World          5          Hello         Hello
```